# In Dart HOW to query Element in nested template?

Tags: html, dom, asynchronous, dart

I have some nested template in Dart, like below:

```
<template id="id1">
<template id="id2">
<input type= id={{xxx}}>
</template>
</template>
```

In this case, how to query the input element? I tried nested Timer.run but it dose not work.

```
query("#id1").model = xxxx
Timer.run({ query("#id2").model=xxxxx;
   Timer.run({ print(query(xxx));});
});
```

Dose any one have any suggestion?

Thanks!

========================================================================

Note: The nested template is actually in a table, the codes are below:

```
    <div style="cursor:crosshair; -webkit-user-select: none; user-select: none;">
    <table id="base_table" style="border-collapse:collapse; position: absolute; top:200px; left:200px; width:800px; height:400px" border="2">
    <template id="table" repeat>  
    <tr>
    <template id={{id}} repeat>  
    <td>  <label style="border:0px; height:18px; width:80px" id={{Cell_ID}}> {{Cell_data}} </label> </td>
    </template>
    </tr>
    </template>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a MutationObserver:

```
final observer = new MutationObserver(() {
  ... code here ...

  observer.disconnect();
})..observe(node, childList: true, subtree: true);
```

Soon, this method will be available in PolymerElement:

```
onMutation(() => ... code here ...);
```

It will automatically disconnect the observe, as above. The implementation is straightforward:

```
void onMutation(Node node, void listener(MutationObserver obs)) {
  final observer = new MutationObserver(() {
    listener(observer);
    observer.disconnect();
  })..observe(node, childList: true, subtree: true);
}
```

So for your particular example, paste the onMutation function, then write it like this:

```
var id1 = query("#id1");
id1.model = xxxx
onMutation(id1.parent, (_) {
    var id2 = query("#id2");
    id2.model = xxxxx;
    onMutation(id2.parent, (_) {
      print(query(xxx));
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you find any examples for me? Sorry I don't quite understand the explanation.

Comment: sure, I added example

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am applying your advice my code to see whether the problem could be solved.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with MutationObserver actually. I just tried it with an example and it dosenot work. Can you see it? Below is the link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927901/in-dart-why-the-code-below-about-mutationobserver-dose-not-work