# In Dart why the code below (about MutationObserver) dose not work?

Tags: dom, dart, dart-webui

I modified one the Dart polymer example to test MutationObserver. It does not work! Any suggestion?

This is the HTML code:

```
<body>   
<ul>      
  <template id="tmpl" repeat>
    <li>{{}}</li>
  </template>
</ul>
</body>
```

This is Dart code:

```
MutationObserver observer = new MutationObserver(_onMutation);
observer.observe(query('#tmpl'), childList: true, subtree: true); 
List timestamps = toObservable([]); 
query('#tmpl').model = timestamps;

new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
    timestamps.add(new DateTime.now());
});

_onMutation(List<MutationRecord> mutations, MutationObserver observer) {
 print('hello test MutationObserver');  **//there is not any print!!!!!!!!!!!**
}
```

Any idea about why it would not work?

[Note: The webpage display is fine, problem is just about the MutationObserver]

Thanks!

Comment: Here's an example of mutation observers: https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/tree/master/web/mutation_observers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want to listen on #tmpl, but on its parentNode. HTML Template element expands its contents as siblings when a model is set. Try this change:

```
observer.observe(query('#tmpl').parent, childList: true, subtree: true);
```

Comment: Confirmed! And obvious when I see it :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that mutation observer events can cross the shadow boundary.

If you put the `<template>` into a custom element, the mutation observers will work.

Here is an example:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

@CustomTag("my-element")
class MyElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  final List<String> timestamps = toObservable([]);
  MutationObserver observer;

  created() {
    super.created();

    observer = new MutationObserver(_onMutation);
    observer.observe(getShadowRoot('my-element').query('#timestamps'), childList: true, subtree: true);

    new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
      timestamps.add(new DateTime.now().toString());
    });
  }

  // Bindings, like repeat, happen asynchronously. To be notified
  // when the shadow root's tree is modified, use a MutationObserver.

  _onMutation(List<MutationRecord> mutations, MutationObserver observer) {
    print('${mutations.length} mutations occurred, the first to ${mutations[0].target}');
  }
}
```

The custom element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <ul id="timestamps">
      <template repeat="{{ts in timestamps}}">
        <li>{{ts}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The main HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <link rel="import" href="my_element.html">
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-element></my-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some times I can not use polymer-element.

Comment: When can't you use polymer element?

Comment: Currently I haven't learned how to communicate between the main() function and <polymer-element>. In case the data need to transferred back and forth between main() and the <polymer-element>, I don't know how to do that. Just like this: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12440

Comment: Create a custom element that wraps your whole app, and put the data in there. It's immediately available as a binding. Join us on web-ui@dartlang.org list and we'll help you out.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. My whole app is too big and not convenient to wrap it into <polymer-element>. I hope there would be a very convenient way to communicate between <polymer-element> and main(). I can wait anyway. Right now my question is that, since binding dose not work, is there any alternative way available for communication between <polymer-element> and main()?

Comment: I found that the code has to live somewhere, putting it into a PolymerElement makes it easily available to my HTML. What do you mean communication? What do you want to communicate? (this is a good question for the mailing list, hope to see you there! :)