# DOM change listener in Dart lang

Tags: dart

I want to have a script execute when the contents of a DIV change, in a different way, I want to listen to specific nodes/child changes, I found something in JavaScript called "DOMSubtreeModified" at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQErD/1/),

```
$("#someDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});
```

is there something similar in DART?

Comment: Since Dart compiles to Javascript, and most browsers don't provide a subtree-modified event, you can't do it in Dart.

Comment: You can use MutationObserver for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927901
http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @Barmar Dart compiles to JavaScript for modern browsers. If a modern browser can do it, Dart can (probably) do it.

Comment: @SethLadd The question is whether a modern browser can do it. That `DOMSubstreeModified` event is something that was proposed, but never widely implemented, I believe.

Comment: @Barmar, Actually my question is about the way doing it in DART, as it is possible in JS at modern browsers, sorry if my question appeared generic, or was not clear enough. thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Gunter Zochbauer,
Along with the recommended sites you gave, I found [this](http://japhr.blogspot.com/2014/02/mutationobserver-as-best-dart-practice.html) about MountainObserver in DART, and the below code worked perfectly for me :)

```dart
main(){
     ...
     Element myDiv = querySelector('#my-element');
     var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, _) {
          mutations.forEach((mutation) {
               print('number of direct nodes here are: ${myDiv.nodes.length}');;
         });
     });
     observer.observe(myDiv, childList: true); 
     ....
  }
```

in the index.html, I've:

```dart
<div id='my-element'></div>
```